# Notifications in background

Tags: swift, xcode, apple-push-notifications

I work on application in swift3, my application receive data from web server, I need my application push notification when new item added in server side, Even when my application is closed, without consuming mobile resource or periodically update, How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Push notifications does not consume resources, your app must not be open to make it work, so it looks like the solution to your problem is just to implement them on your server and app.

Please note that the user will be prompt to accept or decline the use of push notifications, and based on his answer he will receive or not your messages.

To know how to implement push notifications this tutorial might help you.

https://www.raywenderlich.com/123862/push-notifications-tutorial

This is the official apple documentation about push notifications:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/APNSOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH8-SW1

The official apple documentation explains how to implement the communication between your server and APNs.

Hope it is enough for you to get started with that. :)

Comment: I would like to make my app like as facebook or any other social media app, which when one add comment which will notify user, is this capable?

Comment: yes. If you read about APNs in the apple official doc you will be able to do something like that. at any comment you will send a request to your server that will decide if to contact APNs to send a notification to interested users or not. All depends by your logic. If you follow the tutorial and the documentation I linked in my answer you should not have problems.

Comment: Are there is any other service that to do that without cost, i.e, for free?

Comment: APNs is free. you have to implement the communication with the apple's server and you have to implement the app side for receiving push notifications.